# iOS like (partial) slowmotion with easing in Premiere CC

Tags: premiere, slowmotion, iphone

i'm curently in the 30 days trail of Premiere CC (and own Premiere Elements 12), and i try to produce iOS like (partial) slowmotion with easing between the different speeds. I already slowed down a entire clip using "Speed/Duration".

How do I get a transition between the different speeds?

Example in FCP: http://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.1/#ver41a2cd3ae

Comment: Not an expert in premiere, but take a look into Speed Ramps or Time Remapping, like: https://vimeo.com/74355917

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm looking for. But unfortunately, the audio remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Time Remapping effect, and just use keyframes to ease in/out of different speeds.

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/duration-speed.html